# Stylish safe way to check for nullability of multiple values with Detekt

Tags: kotlin, detekt

I'm using Danger Detekt (static code quality measurement system based on ktlint). I've got a function that fetches data from 8 different endpoints. Then I need to check if these values are not null and if so I return complex data type built with these values, but if any of these values is null I have to return null. Let's say it looks like this:

```
val first = endpoint.get()
...
```

then I could check it with complex if statement, but Detekt will complain about complex condition. So I changed it to this:

```
val first = endpoint.get() ?: return null
...
```

But Detekt is now complaining about too many return statements since I have to add it to every fetch.

Is there any handy Kotlin function for such problem?

Comment: Using `?: return null` each time looks like a perfectly good approach, whatever Detekt might say.  The only other option that springs to mind is to store all your return values in a list and then `if (null in returnValues)` — but that would try to fetch all 8 endpoints even if the first one failed, which is clearly unnecessary and inefficient…

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fold to collect the results of each `get`, but make the accumulator `null` as soon as you hit a null result (and check that before you attempt each `get` call). So it latches into a failed state:

```
typealias Result = String

data class Endpoint(val name: String, val result: Result?) {
    fun get(): Result? {
        println("Getting endpoint $name - result is $result")
        return result
    }
}

val endpoint1 = Endpoint("One", "Result 1")
val endpoint2 = Endpoint("Two", null)
val endpoint3 = Endpoint("Three", "Result 3")
val endpoints = listOf(endpoint1, endpoint2, endpoint3)

// I heard yr linter hates returns
fun resultCollector(results: List<Result>?, endpoint: Endpoint) = 
    results?.run {
        endpoint.get()?.let { results.plus(it) }
    }

fun main() {   
    endpoints.fold(emptyList<Result>(), ::resultCollector)
}

>> Getting endpoint One - result is Result 1
   Getting endpoint Two - result is null
   (end)
```

You could use a lambda instead of a function reference but I just wanted it to be clear - you pass a result list through the folder, and the function does a couple of null checks (checks the `results` list, checks the result of the `get` call). Both of those checks can evaluate to null, and that's what the function will return as the next accumulator - the endpoint code is only executed (and an actual `Result` returned) if you don't hit a null

Personally I think that level of explanation means that maybe just a few early returns is much easier to follow and probably looks a whole lot neater when they're lined up too. Up to you though!